# Passing huge JSON to Sidekiq Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

One of the features of the application which I am currently working on is photo upload. Customers upload photos in frontend and photos are passed to rails backed and then stored on Amazon S3.

I have noticed that a huge amount of request time is spent uploading photos to s3. The photos are uploaded one by one so latency is multiplied. It would be great if I could somehow store photos temporarily in RAM and increase request speed.

I have thinked about running a Sidekiq job with a file as params but [according to  sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple) passing a huge object is not good practise. How can I solve this in another vay ?

Comment: how about [direct upload](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem by using an API to generate a presigned url and using cognito to upload the image on s3 and get the image link.

Answer (score 0):

nginx/puma running on machine A should save the image as a local file. Run Sidekiq on the same machine A and pass the filename to a job in a host-specific queue for Sidekiq to process. That way you can pass a file reference without worrying which machine will process it.

Make sure Sidekiq deletes the file so you don't fill up the disk!

https://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/